# In Node.js how can I dynamically change the name of a variable based on the User trying to access it?

Tags: node.js, json

I am trying to access a variable where `USER_ID` is dynamic:

```
jsonParsed.users.[USER_ID].userID;
```

The `USER_ID` will be a large number based on a discord users ID. The user.id is correctly matched up to the id in the json file.

```
function scrumJoin(user) {
  let USER_ID = user.id; //Example: user.id = 147477029364979999
  let content = fs.readFileSync('scrumUsers.json');
  let jsonParsed = JSON.parse(content);
  console.log('JSON parsed user ID: \n' + jsonParsed.users.[USER_ID].userID); //point of failure
}
```

JSON file:

```
{
  "users": [
      {
          "1111111111111111": [{
              "userID": 1111111111111111,
              "phase": 1
          }]
      },
      {
          "147477029364979999": [{
              "userID": 147477029364979999,
              "phase": 1
          }]
      }
  ]
}
```

I want `USER_ID` to dynamically change based on who is accessing the file. I know this is probably a really simple solution, but I am struggling to figure out how to word it in google and I'm pretty sure GPT is incorrect.

Chat GPT is telling me to format it like this:

```
jsonParsed.users[USER_ID].userID
```

but I'm pretty sure that specifies the location of the section I am trying to access in the array, not the name of the section itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making it more complicated than necessary due to your data structure. However, here's how to do it.

For the data structure:

```
let jsonParsed = {
  "users": [
      {
          "1111111111111111": [{
              "userID": 1111111111111111,
              "phase": 1
          }]
      },
      {
          "147477029364979999": [{
              "userID": 147477029364979999,
              "phase": 1
          }]
      }
  ]
}
```

In order to extract a user with given user id you'd have to do:

```
let user;

// Loop through the users array:
for (let i=0; i<jsonParsed.users.length; i++) {
    let u = jsonParsed.users[i];

    // If the user object contains the USER_ID then
    // we've found the user:
    if (u[USER_ID] !== undefined) {
        user = u[USER_ID][0];
        break;
    }
}
```

I've written the above for clarity. The code is as simple as possible so that it is as understandable as possible. You can write it in more modern functional style:

```
let user = jsonParsed.users
               .find(u => u[USER_ID] !== undefined)[USER_ID][0];
```

That's more compact but there's also a lot more to unpack. However it means exactly the same thing as the code above, find the object in the array that has the USER_ID as the key.

#### Better data structure.

A better data structure is to simply use an object instead of an array:

```
let jsonParsed = {
  "users": {
      "1111111111111111": [{
          "userID": 1111111111111111,
          "phase": 1
      }],
      "147477029364979999": [{
          "userID": 147477029364979999,
          "phase": 1
      }]
  }
}
```

With this the code simply becomes:

```
let user = jsonParsed.users[USER_ID][0];
```

That's it, no loops, no filter or find. Just access it directly.

You can even improve it further by removing the array that wraps the user object:

```
let jsonParsed = {
  "users": {
      "1111111111111111": {
          "userID": 1111111111111111,
          "phase": 1
      },
      "147477029364979999": {
          "userID": 147477029364979999,
          "phase": 1
      }
  }
}
```

With this data structure your code is simply:

```
let user = jsonParsed.users[USER_ID];
```

Comment: Thanks this was super informative. I haven't worked with json much, so I was basing my structure off of much more complicated examples I had seen. Removing the arrays makes things a lot easier to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Changed the formatting of my json file to no longer include unnecessary arrays:

```
{
  "users": {
     "147473029364979999": {
      "username": "username1",
      "userID": "147473029364979999",
      "phase": 1
    },
    "147473029364908888": {
      "username": "username2",
      "userID": "147473029364978888",
      "phase": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Was able to retrieve the correct data based on a dynamic `USER_ID` with the following code:

```
function scrumJoin(user) {
  let USER_ID = user.id;
  let content = fs.readFileSync('scrumUsers.json');
  console.log('JSON content: \n' + content);
  let jsonParsed = JSON.parse(content);
  console.log('JSON parsed: \n' + jsonParsed.users[USER_ID].phase);
}
```

Comment: If you don't need to modify the JSON file you can simply require it to load it in your program: `let jsonParsed = require('scrumUsers.json')`.